# Рандомный background от времени суток

Tags: javascript, jquery, дата

Привет!
У меня есть такой код JS:

```js
var randomBackground = []; // Настраиваем рандомные background`ы для шапки
var time_unix = $.now(); // Текущее время в формате Unix
var dt = new Date(time_unix);
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds(); // Текущее время в формате HH.MM.SS

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (time >= '7:00:00' && time <= '12:00:00') {
        randomBackground = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg'];
        $("header-content-block").css('background-image', 'url(/templates/default/img/backgrounds/' + randomBackground[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomBackground.length)] + ')');
    }
});
```

Если делать обычную проверку с alert, работает ли условие `time >= '7:00:00'` - то выводит false.

Как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сравниваете две строки, вероятнее всего строки в JS сравниваются по длине. Так делать не нужно, если вы хотите сравнивать время.

Нет необходимости использовать обертку над new Date(). `$.now()` избыточная функция.

Если вам нужно сравнивать часы, просто сравнивайте часы.

```
var time = new Date();

$(document).ready(function() {
    var hours = time.getHours();
    if (7 <= hours && hours <= 12) {
        // Делайте все что нужно
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @MyZik, во время тестирования заметил возможный bug в Google Chrome 63. Следите за [этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756255/javasript-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC).

Comment: @MyZik, обратите внимание на изменения. Я допустил одну глупую ошибку, сравнивать то нужно `hours`.

Comment: да, я так и подумал, что Вы опечтались :) на продакшене всё нормально.

Ещё раз большое спасибо!