# Баг со временем в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, отладка, время, chromium

Особого смысла объяснять код не вижу. Дело в том, как этот код работает.

Chrome 63.0.3239.84

```js
var time = new Date();

var hours = time.getHours();
console.log(hours, hours === 17, time <= 17, 17 <= 17);
console.log(15 <= time);
console.log(time <= 17);
```

[image: Bug]

Это я допустил какую-то фундаментальную ошибку в JS? Или всё-таки Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А так? time - это же объект времени

```js
var time = new Date();

var hours = time.getHours();
console.log(hours, hours === 17, hours <= 17, 17 <= 17);
console.log(15 <= hours);
console.log(hours <= 17);
```

Comment: Оу, даже слов нет...

Comment: @VasiliyRusin проблема в том, что сравнивали time, вместо hours? :)

Comment: @MyZik, уже поправил в ответе.